# How to refer to document methods such as getElementByID in a tsx file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm converting plain js files to typescript within a React application.

`document` is showing an error though when I use methods such as `document.getElementById("login-username")`

How can I refer to `document` methods in this typescript document?

```
import React, { useState, FormEvent, ChangeEvent } from 'react';

interface loginProps {
  username: string,
  setUsername(username: string): string,
  setLoggedIn(loggedIn: boolean): boolean
}

export default function Login(props: loginProps) {
  const { username, setUsername, setLoggedIn } = props;
  const [err, setErr] = useState('');
  function handleUsername(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> ) {
    const user = document.getElementById("login-username").value.trim();
    const password = document.getElementById("login-password").value.trim();
    if (user === '') { setErr('blank username'); } else {  //ugly, will fix later
      if (password === '') { setErr('blank password'); } else {
        if (user.length < 2) { setErr('username must be at least 2 characters'); } else {
          setUsername(user);
          setLoggedIn(true);
        }
      }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  function setUserField(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleUsername} autoComplete="yes" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
      <span style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Login</span>
      <br /><br />
      <label htmlFor="login-username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" 
        padding="20px"
        value={username}
        onChange={setUserField}
        name="login-username"
        id="login-username" />
      <label htmlFor="login-password">Password:</label>
      ...
```

Comment: Don't use DOM. Do it the React way. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Because you should be able to use the `document` object without a problem: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=2&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAmJgFcC2BTMKAOgHM8oBRAGz30ICEBPASTQAoByKPaASzBIwAjACYAzBwCUAKF5wYbBCEnxERfmDwAnABIAVALIAZFDABE3PgJgAWAKwA2M0A But really, you should be using refs here.

Answer (score 1):

So in ReactJS it's best to use refs
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
 class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Basically create a variable to access your element. Add the ref attribute on the specified element and assign it the variable. You will then have access to the element in the DOM as per React's standard.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example from the docs using hooks, [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What would be the approach for functional components?

Comment: @Michael `useRef()`

Comment: Still, I believe using controlled fields is even more reacty

Comment: @MichaelDurrant This answer is giving you the reference to the DOM element. However, it seems like you want to use it to get the values of the input. There is a better way of doing it using controlled fields. Please refer to reactjs.org/docs/forms.html